# Keeping the menu dropdown open after clicking?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

Suppose I wanted to open a couple of bookmarks in my browser. To do this, I use the menu bar. I click on «Bookmarks» to reveal the dropdown with all my bookmarks and then select the bookmark. The dropdown closes and the browser opens the bookmark. Now I have to click on «Bookmarks» again and click on another bookmark, the dropdown again closes and the browser opens the bookmark. Is there a way to keep the menu dropdown opened after I clicked on an item? That way I could click multiple items in the dropdown way faster! I remember being able to do this in Windows XP some years ago and it was really handy. I think I had to hold down ALT when clicking on the menu item.

Thanks for any advice!

**Edit for clarification**: I'm only using the bookmark menu as an easy to understand example. I'm looking for a way to do this system-wide!

Answer (score 2):

control F2 key gets menu bar focus in full screen app mode
set F Keys to standard function keys via keyboard prefs
keyboard shortcuts "Focus to Menu Bar" 
default is Control F2 for menu bar focus
control F2 for dock focus

Answer (score 0):

May depend on the browser but at least in Safari, Firefox and Chrome, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-clicking on a bookmark folder opens a new tab for every bookmark in the folder. May require some bookmark reorganization though.

Comment: Thanks, but I was just using the bookmark example as an easy example. I am more interested in doing this in other applications and the finder. Ideally, there should be a way to make this work system-wide!

Comment: I fear there isn't...

Comment: I don't know of a way either, unless there's a menu haxie out there somewhere that still works these days. (First desktop I remember that let you do this was the Commodore Amiga...)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is go to the Bookmarks Menu (Bookmarks --> Show all Bookmarks) and then select Bookmarks Menu from the collections tree to drag and drop links on a new tab

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I am aware that this is not a direct answer, but it might help with the problem anyway. This could be an XY problem.</sub>

If you find yourself using the same menu items repeatedly, use their keyboard shortcuts. If they don't have shortcuts by default, assign your own in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Applications*.

[image]